# How SVM determines the margin with text data?

Tags: nlp, svm

SVM is a geometric algorithm that tries to maximize the margin between two classes by drawing a hyper-plane between them. This is understandable with numbers as data points. However, I don't understand how the margin and hyper-plane are determined when the data is text? I would appreciate it if someone could give an example of how SVM deals with text.

Comment: Internally most machine learning algorithms only work on numbers. So your text is somehow converted to a numeric representation and then dealt.

Answer (score 0):

Generally in machine learning textual input is converted to a dictionary of textual data and corresponding numeric values. Let's say you have 3 words in your corpus: apples, oranges, bananas. The dictionary may look like

apples: 1

oranges: 2

bananas: 3

So you pass 1, 2, 3 to your model and convert back numerical values to textual data when you get your results. For example, if you got somehow a result of 2, it means oranges.